# JPA - jackson - @JsonAutoDetect - circle relationship OneToMany - preventing LOOP loading errors

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, serialization, jackson

I have Task and RelatedTask entities:
Every task can have a many related tasks, but every there can be some kind of circle :

Task #1 has 3 related tasks - > #2, #3, #4 and task #4 has related tasks #1 and #5

1 -> 2, 3, 4 -> 1, 5

This circle making error in loading, how can I prevent it ?

Here is my entities:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long taskId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TaskRelated> relatedTasks = new ArrayList<TaskRelated>();
}

@JsonAutoDetect 
@Entity
public class TaskRelated {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long taskRelatedId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="relatedTaskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Task relatedTask;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="taskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Task task;
}
```

The ERROR is when JACKSON try to serialize it:

```
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
```

If I set @JsonIgnore to relatedTask like :

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="relatedTaskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Task relatedTask;
```

There is no error, but I have no data about related tasks as objects,
Do you have any ideas ? 
Thank you!

Comment: What kind of error occurs?

Comment: added more information, tnx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be two approaches, which are:

1. If you want to continue using `org.codehaus.jackson...` you should consider using `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` annotations. Example:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Task {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long taskId;

       @JsonManagedReference
       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       private List<TaskRelated> relatedTasks = new ArrayList<TaskRelated>();
   }

   @Entity
   public class TaskRelated {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long taskRelatedId;

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="relatedTaskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       private Task relatedTask;

       @JsonBackReference
       @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name="taskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       private Task task;
   }
   ```
2. If you want to upgrade jackson2.+, it can be found [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/). You can use the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation with id generated using ObjectIdGenerators. More information can be found [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity/).

   ```
   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
   @Entity
   public class Task {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long taskId;

       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       private List<TaskRelated> relatedTasks = new ArrayList<TaskRelated>();
   }

   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
   @Entity
   public class TaskRelated {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Long taskRelatedId;

       @OneToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="relatedTaskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       private Task relatedTask;

       @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name="taskId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
       private Task task;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

This works (you need to save TaskRelated entities)

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long taskId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TaskRelated> relatedTasks = new ArrayList<TaskRelated>();

}

@Entity
public class TaskRelated {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long taskRelatedId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="relatedTaskId")
    private Task relatedTask;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="taskId")
    private Task task;

}
```

Comment: @prilia Did you make an attempt to try the solution I gave before commenting that it doesnt answer your question. Try this solution and then comment if it hasnt solved your problem

Comment: I would accept your comment and delete this answer only if you try and tell that it doesnot solve your problem as I am sure this solution should solve your issue